# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent not found from bundle [camel-activemq]

Tags: activemq-classic, karaf

I tried to deploy a sample activemq application into karaf.While deploying and starting the bundle i got this error.please help me to solve this.
I have installed all required activemq components into karaf.
still getting the following error.

```
karaf@root()> Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-7" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Can
not find class [org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent] for bean with name 'activemq' defined in URL [bundle://1171
.4:0/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.camel.component
.ActiveMQComponent not found from bundle [camel-activemq]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:575)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:910)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactor
y.java:609)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationConte
xt.java:932)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExec
utionApplicationContext.java:69)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionA
pplicationContext.java:355)
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegated
ExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefr
eshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent not found from bundle [camel-ac
tivemq]
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:103)
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:156)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1267)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent not found by camel-activemq [11
71]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1844)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:937)
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:99)
        ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This camel-activemq project is an upstream archetype you can use it for your quick starter of camel.
To use it in karaf, you need to add the bundle manifest.

first need to change the packing to bundle,

```
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
```

then add this part

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <instructions>
        <Bundle-SymbolicName>camel-activemq</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        <Import-Package>*,org.apache.activemq.camel.component</Import-Package>
      </instructions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss the activemq-camel feature.

Log into karaf and issue the following commands:

For Karaf 2.3.x:

```
> features:chooseurl activemq
> features:install activemq-camel
```

For Karaf 3.0.x:

```
karaf@root()> feature:repo-add activemq
karaf@root()> feature:install activemq-camel
```

The activemq-camel feature will also install activemq-client & camel-jms.

You may need to provide a specific version number in the repository command depending on what versioning information is embedded in your bundle. E.g.:

```
karaf@root()> feature:repo-add activemq 5.10.0
```